# Ходить по сайтам из файла и парсить название

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер

Есть список сайтов в текстовом файле. Нужно зайти на каждый сайт и взять название сайта из хедера. Пробовал не просто из файла, а сам задавал название сайта, но не получилось (использовал pandas).

```
import pandas as pd

tables = pd.read_html("https://site.com/")

print(title)
```

Ещё не работал с парсерами. Что можете посоветовать?

Comment: pandas не совсем (совсем не) для парсинга. Стоит обратить внимание на [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/), а если из html что-то достать, то начать с [beautifull soup](https://python-scripts.com/beautifulsoup-html-parsing).

Comment: в дополнение к вышесказанному, существует фреймворк для парсинга - scrapy

Comment: Библиотека `Pandas` нужна только в том случае, если хотите доставать с сайта исключительно таблицы. В других случаях она не при делах.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#получаем данные
r = requests.get("https://google.com")

#создаём html файл
with open('html.html', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
        output_file.write(r.text)

#открываем html файл
html = open('html.html', encoding="utf-8").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

#ищем заголовок
title = soup.find('title')

print(title)
```

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы он взял title каждого сайта из файла? Нужно сначала создать список и чтобы r=requests.get с элементами оттуда работал или можно напрямую из файла брать?